# Order By em 2 tabelas MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom dia!
Estou passando por mals momentos e gostaria da ajuda de vocês com este problema!

Vamos lá, estou fazendo um select no MYSQL onde são selecionadas varias tabelas, no opencart para gerar um XML para anuncios facebook.

Meu código XML esta assim

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id as product_idT1, t1.manufacturer_id as manufaturer, t1.price as price, t1.date_added as dataAdd, t1.quantity as quantity, t2.name as nameT2, t2.description as descriptionT2, t3.name as nameT3, t4.name as nameT4, t5.image, t6.name as nameT6, t7.query as urlT7, t7.keyword as keyword 
FROM oc_product t1 
INNER JOIN oc_product_description t2 ON (t1.product_id = t2.product_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_manufacturer t3 ON (t1.manufacturer_id = t3.manufacturer_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_option_value_description t4 
INNER JOIN oc_product_image t5 ON (t1.product_id = t5.product_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_stock_status t6 ON (t1.stock_status_id = t6.stock_status_id) 
INNER JOIN oc_url_alias t7 
WHERE t7.query like CONCAT('%', t1.product_id , '%') 
GROUP BY product_idT1 ASC
```

Só que no caso, a tabela de imagens oc_product_image precisa estar em ordem DECRESCENTE pois quero a ultima imagem.

Estou usando PHP.

Obrigado!

Comment: ORDER BY t5.image DESC, t1.product_id

Comment: Show... muito obrigado! Mas ainda não é o que preciso =/

Comment: Explique melhor sua necessidade, se a solução não é um simples `order by`, qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: Preciso que ele retorne em ordem decrescente Ex: 

Produto 1(oc_product) - Foto 1 (oc_product_image)
Produto 2(oc_product) - Foto 2 (oc_product_image)

Mas não sei o porque a minha primeira foto no cadastro, esta ficando como a última! 
Deu para entender ^^

Comment: Ta um pouco confuso ainda, mas pelo que entendi seria simples: `ORDER BY t5.product_id DESC`. Porém no seu último comentário, sinceramente tive a impressão de vc estar querendo ordem Ascendente e não Descendente... mas veja aí se a solução que postei atende sua necessidade.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo!
Muito Obrigado

Comment: Reativando novamente a questão, esta query seria para listar todos os produtos mas não esta listando, ela esta ocultando cerca de 90 resultados, poderiam me dizer onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça `ORDER BY t5.product_id DESC`, assim ordenará pela ordem de cadastro do produto.
O fato de não estar listando todos os produtos, deve estar relacionado aos `INNER JOINS` ou mesmo ao `WHERE`.
Troque os `Inners` por `LEFT JOIN` (apenas para teste) e remova o `Where`.
Assim você descobrirá o que está impedindo de buscar todos os produtos.

Comment: Vou testar, e já lhe dou um retorno! Muito obrigado

Comment: Fiz da seguinte maneira:

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.product_id as product_idT1, t1.manufacturer_id as manufaturer, t1.price as price, t1.date_added as dataAdd, t1.quantity as quantity, t2.name as nameT2, t2.description as descriptionT2, t3.name as nameT3, t4.name as nameT4, t5.image as imagemT5, t6.name as nameT6, t7.query as urlT7, t7.keyword as keyword, t8.product_id, t8.price as produtoDesconto 
FROM oc_product t1 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description t2 ON (t1.product_id = t2.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_manufacturer t3 ON (t1.manufacturer_id = t3.manufacturer_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_option_value_description t4 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_image t5 ON (t1.product_id = t5.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_stock_status t6 ON (t1.stock_status_id = t6.stock_status_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_special t8 ON (t1.product_id = t8.product_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_url_alias t7 
ORDER BY t5.product_id DESC
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY t5.product_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 10

pode me ajudar no que estou fazendo errado?
Obrigado

Comment: Você não deve postar em resposta uma questão a respeito de um problema. Ou edite sua pergunta inicial ou use os comentários.   Porém nesse *SQL* repare que o *JOIN* com a tabela *oc_url_alias T7* não possui a cláusula **ON** (É necessário!)